# apache redirect to tomcat not working

Tags: apache, tomcat, redirect

I'm trying to redirect Apache Webserver to Tomcat in AWS Linux.when i pass CName , it have to validate ping sso and then come back to apache. There are no static components in Apache, i am just using it as web layer to redirect to tomcat. Tomcat is running on port 8080. Apcahe is running on port 80. App ELB is working. when i pass **exampleCNAME.com**, it validates PING and it goes to sample "index.html" page of apache. it failing to go to Tomcat. I can't redirect from  Apache to Tomcat .

i treied with these configurations
Server.xml

```
  Server port="11401" shutdown="msp_EXAMPLE_tomcat_01_SHTDN">
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8080" />
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger" />
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true"    autoDeploy="true">
                <Valve    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" conditionUnless="NO_ACCESS_LOG" pattern="%{X-Forwarded-For}i %{CUSTOMER_APP_DATA_REF_KEY}i %{remote_user}i %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{ssoId}i&quot;" />
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 RewriteEngine on
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyErrorOverride On
    ProxyRequests off

 ProxyPass / http://internal-EXAMPLE-ELB-12345.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/example/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://internal-EXAMPLE-ELB-12345.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/example/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Add Tomcat's port number (8080) to your `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` lines, i.e. `ProxyPass / http://internal-EXAMPLE-ELB-12345.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/example/`

Comment: @JozefChocholacek . i tried by giving 8080 aswell, it didn't work. it giving 404, URL not found error